# Resnet34: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 14 and 13. Shapes are [16,14,14] and [16,13,13]

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, train-test-split, unet-neural-network

I am a bit despair to try getting ‘resnet34’ to work with no success. I have a dataset with 2100 images and 7 classes, 300 images by class. I load them in a loop that way:

```py
img = cv2.imread(file)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Then I got a datafreme like that:

```py
dtf = dtf[["Name","img","Label","y"]]
```

where in column “img” are saved the images and “y” is just a factorization of the label column to make the labels int:

```py
dtf["y"] = dtf["Label"].factorize(sort=True)[0]
```

And I transform the images like that:

```py
dtf["img"] = dtf["img"] /255
```

Then, I divide the dtf in validation and training sets and reshape the images, that are 200x200, as recomended by tutorial I followed:

```py
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

x_train = preprocess_input(X_train)
x_val = preprocess_input(X_test)
N = x_train[0].shape[-1]   #grayscale
input_shape=(None, None, N)

print(N)

x_train2=[]
for i in x_train:    
  x_train2.append(i.reshape(200,200,N))

x_val2=[]
for i in x_val:    
  x_val2.append(i.reshape(200,200,N))

x_train=x_train2
x_val=x_val2
```

So now I just define the model, compile and try to fit it:

```py
model = sm.Unet('resnet34', classes=7, activation='softmax',encoder_weights=None, input_shape=(None, None, N))
model.compile('Adam', loss=bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[iou_score])

model.fit(
    x=np.asarray(np.array(x_train)),
    y=np.array(y_train),
    batch_size=16,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(np.array(x_val), np.array(y_test)),
)
```

However, when it starts the fitting, I get the next error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "decoder_stage0_concat" (type Concatenate). 

Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 14 and 13. Shapes are [16,14,14] and [16,13,13]. for '{{node model_4/decoder_stage0_concat/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model_4/decoder_stage0_upsampling/resize/ResizeNearestNeighbor, model_4/stage4_unit1_relu1/Relu, model_4/decoder_stage0_concat/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [16,14,14,512], [16,13,13,256], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <3>. Call arguments received: • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(16, 14, 14, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(16, 13, 13, 256), dtype=float32)']
```

Please, any help would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: what library do you use here?

Comment: Hello Christoph, 

The modules used for this are:

import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from google.colab import drive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tqdm.notebook  import tqdm
import random

#!pip install segmentation_models
from segmentation_models import Unet
from segmentation_models import get_preprocessing
from segmentation_models.losses import bce_jaccard_loss
from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score

import segmentation_models as sm

any clue?

Thanks,

Comment: don't paste a bunch of lines of code in a comment. that is entirely unreadable. [edit] your question and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing almost identical problems. It seems to be related to the image size. In my case, resizing to 256x256 works, but 257x257 does not. Getting OBE in various decoder parts (decoder_stage2_concat, decoder_stage0_concat) as if the architecture was only compatible with some dimensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).